# Javascript - lodash or native array functions get first item

Tags: javascript, arrays, filter, lodash

I have the following data

```
data: [
    [200, 3],
    [400, 4],
    [2344, 8],
    [34543, 2],
];
```

What I am trying to do with lodash or native filter/map functions is to create 2 arrays.

```
array1 = [200, 400, 2344, 34543];
array2 = [3, 4, 8, 2];
```

I have tried map, filter and lodash first with no luck.

Comment: *I have tried map, filter and lodash* then show what you have tried. Please add your code also...

Comment: Create two arrays. [Loop over the main array](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Guide/Loops_and_iteration). Push the first element of each nested array into array1, and the second element into array2. No `map`, no `filter`, and no `lodash`.

Answer (score 0):

You can use lodash's `_.unzip()` and then get the two arrays via destructuring:

```js
const data = [[200, 3], [400, 4], [2344, 8], [34543, 2]];

const [array1, array2] = _.unzip(data);

console.log(array1);
console.log(array2);
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/lodash.js/4.17.21/lodash.min.js" integrity="sha512-WFN04846sdKMIP5LKNphMaWzU7YpMyCU245etK3g/2ARYbPK9Ub18eG+ljU96qKRCWh+quCY7yefSmlkQw1ANQ==" crossorigin="anonymous" referrerpolicy="no-referrer"></script>
```

Answer (score 0):

```
array1 = data.map(el=>el[0])
array2 = data.map(el=>el[1])
```

Comment: Please read [How do I write a good answer?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer). While this code block may answer the OP's question, this answer would be much more useful if you explain how this code is different from the code in the question, what you've changed, why you've changed it and why that solves the problem without introducing others.

Answer (score 0):

Using `.map()` && `.at()` :

```js
const data=  [
  [200, 3],
  [400, 4],
  [2344, 8],
  [34543, 2],
];

const unzip = arr => [ arr.map(x => x.at(0)),  arr.map(x => x.at(1)) ]

const [left, right] = unzip(data);

console.log(left);
console.log(right);
```